# Expand $f(x)$ into a Fourier cosine series

Tags: fourier-series

Expand $f(x)=x(\pi-x)$ into a Fourier cosine  series on $(0;\pi)$

My idea is to expand the function into an even function on $[-\pi;\pi]$ so that the $b_n=0$ and we'll get a Fourier cosine  series. But I don't know how. Any one help me please?

Comment: Follow [the recipe](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) for a Fourier cosine series on $[0,L]$: $f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n x}{L}\right)$ with
$$a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^{L} f(x)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)\,{\rm d}x$$
For your case $L = \pi$ and $f(x) = x(\pi-x)$. Perform the integral to determine $a_n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But we don't needto expand $f(x)$ into an even function?

Comment: By assuming $f(x)$ only has $\cos$-terms and not $\sin$-terms we are implicitly assuming that $f$ (when evaluated outside of $[0,L]$) is continued as an even function. Note that what you suggest would also work and give the same result, i.e. if you try to compute the Fourier series of an even continued $f(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ by using the standard formulas for this case.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much.